# Ubuntu 16.04 restarts after login, after trying to install CUDA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, cuda

I was trying to install the CUDA Toolkit from the NVDIA website. After I ran

```
$ sudo sh cuda_10.1.105_418.39_linux.run
```

it began the installation, and it finished with errors, which said that I was using X drivers instead of NVIDIA ones, so I followed the first 40 seconds of this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Xy1Uqq9Hbk&t=45s

That is, I went to Additional Drivers and changed from "Using X.Org X server" to "NVDIA binary driver, version 384.130". Then I restarted and now the login page of Ubuntu is displayed with a different resolution, and when I try to log in it reboots and comes back to the log in page.

I have read that the problem is most probably due to installing drivers running a .run file, and that I should purge nvidia and install it again from the shell command line. However, I don't know which version I should install and I don't want to mess it up more.

I don't know if I wrote enough information. If you need more, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it finally. If it helps somebody, what worked for me was to purge the NVIDIA drivers:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
$ sudo reboot
```

So that it could go back to my "xserver-xorg-video-nouveau" driver configuration.